# Java method that tries to change a variable isn't working

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

I am currently coding this bit of a game in which, an enemy (a bat) should have its health drop but it's not working.

```
class BatTest{
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input = "";
    boolean exit = false;
    Bat bat1 = new Bat();
    Inventory MainInv = new Inventory();
    MainInv.smallknife = true;
    System.out.println("A bat has appeared!");
    System.out.println("Health: " + bat1.health + " Attack Strength: " + bat1.damage);
    do{
        System.out.println("Health: " + bat1.health + " Attack Strength: " + bat1.damage);
        System.out.print("What would you like to do: ");
        input = Keyboard.readString();
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Attack")) {
            Abilities.smallknifeMA(bat1.health);
            System.out.println(bat1.health);
        }
        else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            exit = true;
        }
    }while(!exit);
}
```

}

```
//enemyH denotes the health of the enemy

class Abilities {
static double smallknifeMA(double enemyH) {
    enemyH = enemyH - 2.0;
    return enemyH;
}
```

}

```
class Inventory {
boolean smallknife;
boolean startlockerkey;
```

}

I can't really understand why smallknifeMA doesn't lower the variable bat1.health.

Thanks,
Aurora

Comment: Perhaps provide some information about what's not working. Have you tried looking in a debugger to see what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is not pass by reference. This

```
Abilities.smallknifeMA(bat1.health);
```

needs to update `bat1.health`. Something like,

```
bat1.health = Abilities.smallknifeMA(bat1.health);
```

Or, modify `smallknifeMA` to take a `Bat` argument and update the `health` directly. Something like,

```
static void smallknifeMA(Bat bat) {
    bat.health -= 2.0;
}
```

However, it is a bad practice to make your class members `public`; you should probably *encapsulate* this behaviour in `Bat`.

Comment: Thanks you very much! I spent 30 minutes trying to understand this pass by reference thing but the examples given were too complex!